# In orientDB can the following data types be used in graphical database of orientDb or is is possible only in document database of orientDb?

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases

1. Embedded
2. Embedded list
3. Embedded set
4. Embedded map
5. Link
6. Link list
7. Link Set
8. Link map

can these data types used in graph db of orientdb?

Answer (score 1):

They can be used in both. As pointed out in the [OrientDB docs](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Choosing-between-Graph-or-Document-API.html) (some paragraphs quoted below), the Graph DB API is built on top of the Document DB API.

When you create an edge in the Graph DB, the Graph API will create an edge document with in and out links pointing to the vertex documents, and in and out links on the vertex documents pointing to the edge (this is without lightweight edges).

By comparison, when you create a link between Documents, it is only a 'one way pointer' from one document to another, thus the second doesn't know that it has been linked. You can also manually create links this way with vertex/edge documents, in situations where you don't need full graph style pointers.

> In OrientDB, we created 2 different APIs: Document API and Graph API. The Graph API works on top of the Document API. The Document API contains the Document, Key/Value and Object Oriented models.
>
> **Graph API**
>
> {snip}
>
> - Relationships are modeled as Bidirectional Edges. If Lightweight edge setting is active, OrientDB uses Lightweight Edges in cases where edges have no properties, so it has the same impact on speed and space as with Document LINKs, but with the additional bonus to have bidirectional connections. This means you can use the MOVE VERTEX command to refactor your graph with no broken LINKs. For more information how Edges are managed look at Lightweight Edges.
>
> **Document API**
>
> {snip}
>
> - Relationships are only Mono Directional. If you need Bidirectional relationships, it is your responsibility to maintain both LINKs.
> - A Document is an atomic unit, while with Graphs everything is connected as In & Out. For this reason, Graph operations must be done within Transactions. Instead, when you create a relationship between documents with a LINK, the target linked document is not involved in this operation. This results in better Multi-Thread support, especially with insert, deletes and updates operations.

Embedded documents have a different use case though, and work with regular documents and graph-based documents. As indicated in various places [in the docs](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Types.html), `The Records are contained inside the owner. The contained records have no RecordIds and are reachable only by navigating the owner record`.

For a practical example, say you have Person and Email documents, then you embed an email into a person - the email would then not be present when you `select from Email`. If you create a Link from the Person to the Email, there would be a standalone email record, but *you wouldn't know** who used each email when querying the Email's. If you used an edge however (ie use graph db api, which will create and maintain links for you), then you would be able to find which person used an email when querying the Emails.

* *You could always query over every Person to find which records link to a specific Email, but doing so misses the point of using a graph database in the first place.*